# Is fields object from thymeleaf or spring

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-validator

I saw something as below for form validation using Thymeleaf and Spring boot.

```
<p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('datePlanted')}" th:errors="*{datePlanted}">Incorrect date</p>
```

Now I don't understand: where is this field object coming from? Is this something that Spring prepares? I am lost somewhere here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fields.java` is a class presented in package [org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.Fields](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf-spring4/3.0.3.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/spring4/expression/Fields.html)

It's pulled in by `thymeleaf-spring4-xxx.jar`

`#fields.hasErrors` is syntax to call method  `hasErrors()` of `Fields` class.

```
public boolean hasErrors(final String field) {
    return FieldUtils.hasErrors(this.configuration, this.processingContext, field);
}
```

Comment: Where is this class coming from. Can you please give me more information. Thanks

Comment: It's pulled in by thymeleaf-spring4-xxx.jar. Open your dependency jars and look into it

Answer (score 1):

You can look the thymeleaf documentation https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#field-errors

```
<p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('datePlanted')}" th:errors="*{datePlanted}">Incorrect date</p>
```

All tags in here such as th:if, th: errors come from thymeleaf template.
There is nothing in here comes from Spring Boot. Because this is frontend side your application.

Let's have input fields such as using Thymeleaf and you are submitting this is field and then when you call the fields.hasErrors it looks the any error this fields.

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"
                    th:field="*{id}" th:value="*{id}" />
```

Comment: I copied that line from documentation. Not the answer I am looking

Comment: Ok. Is this explanation clear for you ? As you can see, the #fields.hasErrors(...) function receives the field expression as a parameter (datePlanted), and returns a boolean telling whether any validation errors exist for that field. From the documentation : https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#field-errors

Comment: My question is where is this field object coming from and who is setting its propertiees.

Comment: Sorry. I updated my answer. Can you look at that again?

Comment: Again my question is where is this field object coming from and who is setting its properties.

Comment: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/blob/3.0-master/thymeleaf-spring4/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/spring4/expression/Fields.java

Comment: You are not answering my question. Thanks though.